# andengine position a body

Tags: coordinates, andengine, document-body

I am trying to position a body using the physics engine with this code:

```
                float touchX = pp[0];
                float touchY = pp[1];
                float diffX = touchX - mBody.getPosition().x;
                float diffY = touchY -  mBody.getPosition().y;                   
                mBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(( pp[0])  / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT , ( pp[1]) / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT));
```

The X and Y coords are from a TMX tile map and are 32 pixels square, I am trying to get the body in the physics engine to move to certain tiles in a tile map (held in the pp[] array) but instead it moves to a random chaotic path. Is this the right approach to convert X,Y coords and move to that point??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

.setLinearVelocity doesn't move body to certain possition. To do this you need to use .setTransform

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- I tried setTransform() which works but given a number of coordinates it moves the body too quickly

Answer (score 0):

`.setLinearVelocity` is like you add force to the body and make it move, so it doesn't move to the position you want.

`.setTransform` is like you set the position of the body.  So it doesn't move slowly from A to B, but disappears from A and suddenly appears at B

You can easy move it slowly by code yourself.